# bootstrap vue (b-tabs) shows blue outline when clicked in safari browser

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I am using bootstrap vue components, b-tabs is showing outline blue focus border after click in safari browser, it is working fine with chrome and Mozilla

I tried

```
*:focus {outline:none !important}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b-tabs` by default has keyboard navigation enabled to make the tabs component accessible to keyboard only and screen reader users. The WAI-ARIA recommendations for tabbed content recommends that the content area of the tab be given a tabindex of `-1` so that screen reader users can easily jump to that region.

You can disable keyboard navigation with the `no-key-nav` prop (which will also remove the tabindex of `-1` from the tab content area).

https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/tabs#keyboard-navigation

If using styles/classes to remove the outline, and your styles are scoped, you need to use vue-loader's [`Deep selector`](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements), as normally you cannot target child elements of a child component in your component:

https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements:

> With `scoped`, the parent component's styles will not leak into child components. However, a child component's root node will be affected by both the parent's scoped CSS and the child's scoped CSS. This is by design so that the parent can style the child root element for layout purposes.

https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements:

> If you want a selector in scoped styles to be "deep", i.e. affecting child components, you can use the `>>>` combinator.
>
> [...]
>
> Some pre-processors, such as Sass, may not be able to parse `>>>` properly. In those cases you can use the `/deep/` or `::v-deep` combinator instead - both are aliases for `>>>` and work exactly the same.

```html
<style scoped>
.tabs /deep/ .tab-pane:focus {
  outline: none;
}
</style>
```

This will be converted to the following (or similar):

```css
.tabs[data-v-f3f3eg9] .tab-pane:focus { outline: none; }
```

Notice that the `[data-v-xxxxx]` attribute selector is only applied to the root class selector, not any child class selectors.

Answer (score 1):

For latest tabs, this works well.

```
.nav-tabs .nav-link:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```